# Seeking Basemap web services?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, google-maps, basemap, bing-maps, arcgis-online-basemaps

Esri has a base map available through a web service:

http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer

Do Google or Bing, or anybody else have a similar service?

Answer (score 2):

You can still use Bing, you just need to set up an account with Microsoft.

Go to: https://www.bingmapsportal.com/
Sign in with a Microsoft ID (XXX@hotmail.com or XXX@outlook.com)

Under "My Account" you can Create Keys (or view keys that you've alread created).
Pick "Basic" key type will allow desktop use for free to a point (will figure out what limitations there are and post here)...

Go to: C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\bin\SetBingKey.exe
Open it, and copy and paste your Bing key in.

Now you can go into ArcGIS Online and search for the Bing Layers and add them.

You can also use WMS services or others... There's lots out there. ArcGIS Online is one place to look, but many provinces and municipalities have them as well (i.e http://www.data.gov.bc.ca/dbc/geo/wms/index.page )

Answer (score 1):

The *free* Bing use has been phased out:
http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/03/27/using-bing-basemaps/
- but you can enter your credentials if you have them and it will work

There are hacks for Google maps out there:
http://socalgis.org/2014/02/05/my-adventure-with-google-maps-in-arcmap/
http://arcbrutile.codeplex.com/

...but I think those go against agreements from both Companies on usage.

Comment: The Bing basemap(s) works just fine when you enter the key as described in @Cameron's answer. Also, be aware that when you use arcbrutile, the basemaps do not show up if a project needs to be printed.

Comment: @cl3 good to hear!

Comment: absolutely! I was surprised to find that it works again as well! Also, I just exported a pdf from ArcBruTile and the basemap was include (Stamen, Watercolor) which was something I couldn't get to work in the 0.4 version, so double good news.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [GoogleBasemaps for ArcMap](http://hdgooglebasemaps.com/) which seems to provide:

- HD Google Maps
- HD Google Satellite
- Google Hybrid
- Google Live Traffic

for ArcMap.

However, I am not sure whether this service is legal - see https://community.esri.com/ideas/2713?commentID=70216#comment-70216 which says:

> I confirmed with a Google employee that www.hdgooglebasemaps.com violates their terms.

Answer (score 0):

You can access Stamen and MapBox basemaps in ArcGIS online as well.  [Check out this blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/04/01/using-stamen-and-mapbox-tilesets-as-basemaps-in-arcgis-com/).  Basically you can add them in as a 'Tile Layer' under the Add Layer From Web option.  From there you just need the correct link to the tile service, including the correct subdomains.